# Is the Indian female name "Sati" the same as the self-immolating Hindu goddess?

Tags: etymology, names, cognates

I heard about an Indian woman (possibly Hindu) with a given name of Sati the other day. Checking the internet, [this site](http://www.sheknows.com/baby-names/name/sati) confirmed that Sati is an Indian female name.

Is the name "Sati" related to the name of the Hindu goddess [Sati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_(goddess)) who self-immolated, or is it just a coincidence (the name's only two syllables long, so it seems plausible)?

Comment: @closevoter isn't this question about "a single word/single language" as per the help center?

Comment: It can be anything, maybe it's short from "Satan", why not?

Comment: Maybe the name "Igor" is from Norwegian "yesterday", why not, but it's not particularly likely. Or, a Muslim might arbitrarily name a child Mohammed because is "sounds nice", why not, but it's more likely that the obvious explanation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In India it is commonplace to give children the name of a god or a goddess. The  answer to your question is yes.